# Message: Undefined variable: get

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to join my table and it's working but I don't know why I got the following error messages.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: get
Filename: views/tambah_wali.php
Line Number: 13

Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ujikom_sekolah\application\views\tambah_wali.php on line 13
```

This is my controller:

```
public function tambah_wali($kode){

    $data['get']=$this->madm->join_wali_siswa($kode);
    $this->load->view('tambah_wali');
}
```

This is my model:

```
public function join_wali_siswa($kode) {

    $this->db->select('wali_murid.nisn');
    $this->db->from('siswa');
    $this->db->join('wali_murid','siswa.nisn=wali_murid.nisn','right');
    $this->db->where('siswa.nisn',$kode);
    $query=$ambildata=$this->db->get();
    if($ambildata->num_rows > 0)
        return $query;
    else
        return null;
    }
```

This is line 13 on my view:

```
<?php foreach($get->result() as $row): ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your `$data['get']`  in your view seems to be missing when have a $data variable must add it to view like below.

`$data['get'] = $this->madm->join_wali_siswa($kode);`

`$this->load->view('tambah_wali', $data);`